# I need to test my React Native app (Ejected from Expo as Bare Workflow) on my personal device. How do I build it and deploy on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

This is purely for educational purposes, I am not planning to launch it to App Store at all as it is just a project I'm working on for College. I was using Expo managed workflow earlier but had to implement some native libraries, I still need to develop more of the code but since I can't access some third-party library through the Expo iOS app client, I want to be able to see if each features I have implemented work on my personal device.

Is there a way to build the app and install it on my iPhone to test it out? Along with rebuilding again after updating/fixing my codes? I missed the fast refresh feature the Expo app provided but since it is ejected, I am not sure how to test the app while working to finish up the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open it in your iphone , you need a mac and with xcode 11 or greater version. There you have to archive the app and then publish on testflight for to use on other phones or you can connect to iphhone to your mac and run that code.

Hope it helps. feel free for odubts

Comment: Wouldn't test flight require a paid Apple Developer account?

Comment: Then sorry, thank you for suggestions. But to just test my app for personal use, I don't think it is worth paying the full price for an apple developer account for a year just for this Project. As I mentioned, I don't plan to release this app to the App Store. I just want to deploy it to my personal device for demo to my self and my college tutor.

Comment: Yes. Then just plug into your Mac, with a phone or open in an emulator.

Comment: Okay, will try that and get back to you. Thank you :D

Comment: Hi, your second suggestion works! Thank you. So now I can build and test the app. But is there a way to have live refresh every time I make changes to the code? Because right now I have to stop the build and re run every time I make any changes.

Comment: shake your phone and just select the option of live reload

Comment: Is that not an Expo client feature? I'm not running it on Expo.

Edit: Never mind, it works hahaha. Thank you so much Gaurav, You've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Hi again, so I've pressed to reload button after shaking the device. But I'm getting an error after a short freeze on the app saying 'Timeout waiting for modules to be invalidated'.

Comment: maybe a problem with reloading but that helps a lot. Hope you mark it as accepted if it helped you :)

Comment: The reloading isn't working, as mentioned per the error. That is my goal with the question, to be able to build the app on my iPhone and show the preview every time I make changes to the code. Is there any way to fix this error? So I can get reloading to work.

Comment: Never mind, I will just stop the build and rebuild it for now. Thank you for helping me out.